# IIS 7 SSL Name Mismatch Issue with Server on Workgroup?

Tags: ssl, iis-7

I have a Windows 2k8 R2 IIS 7 Web Server that's in a DMZ that's not on a Domain and in a workgroup by itself due to policy. The server name is "server131". I am using a SSL certificate that is issued to "server131.my.domain.com" and accessing the web site via url "app.my.domain.com". This results in a SSL name mismatch.

What is the correct way the web server should be named? Does it have to be on the same domain? When I request a new CSR the common name should be "app.my.domain.com"? Do i need to use a wildcard certificate "*.my.domain.com"?

I have never configured a IIS box with SSL that was in a Workgroup and can't really find any info on this particular setup.

Comment: The server name is unimportant. The website name and the SSL certificate name should match.

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the website binding in IIS to fit your certificate's name.

[image]